# Determine the build status of a c# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

I'm building a simple Visual Studio add-in (for in-house purposes) that will monitor the time it takes to build a solution and log this.

I have it almost where I want it, except for one small issue.

The logging doesn't take into account projects that were "up-to-date" or "skipped"

I'm not too fussed about the skipped part, but I would like to determine if a project is classed "up-to-date" or not. How can I determine this?

My current code hooks into the BuildEvents of the DTE2 object for both the solution and each project, although the OnBuildProjConfigBegin / OnBuildProjConfigDone events only pass through if there were successful or not.

Is there a way to find out if a project is up-to-date during a build event in c#?